# Mac Automator AppleScript: if clipboard starts with defined string, amend clipboard to remove specified character

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm pretty new to AppleScript and Automator and I'm trying to figure out a way to do the following.

The clipboard contains something like `<str://blahblahblah>`

I'd like it to look at what is on the clipboard and if it begins with `<str://` then it will remove the `<` and it will remove a `>` which is at the end of the clipboard data. Then when I go to paste, it will paste with the amended data.

Is this something that is possible, is anyone able to help me figure out how to get this to work in automator? Can I use the normal cmd-c and cmd-v for copy/paste or would it have to be a new shortcut?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automator has two built-in modules to work with the clipboard: `Get Contents of Clipboard` and `Copy to Clipboard`. They are both in the Utilities section. Add the 'Get Contents' to your workflow, then add a `Run AppleScript` module with the following code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theClipText to item 1 of input
    if theClipText begins with "<str://" then
        set theClipText to text 2 through -2 of theClipText
    end if

    return theClipText
end run
```

then add the 'Copy to' module. it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a **Get Contents of Clipboard** action rather than AppleScript's `the clipboard as ...` (seeing as you're running an AppleScript anyway) ?  Either way, I don't think solely testing the first character is a strong enough test, and would suggest: `if theClipText starts with "<str://" then`. But the entire workflow can be replaced with `tell (the clipboard as text) to if it starts with "<str://" and it ends with ">" then set the clipboard to text 2 thru -2`. This does away with the two clipboard actions, and the explicit `run` handler and parameter fiddling.

Comment: PS. It's best to avoid using `characters [of]...` to extract a substring. It not only adds an extra step, creating a `list` that then needs to be coerced back into `text`; but doing this makes it prey to `text item delimiters`, which tends to be an advisable property to set explicitly ahead of any `list` → `text` coercion as good coding practice, even though they default to `""` and ought not to create an issue here. Using `text 2 thru -2 of ...` is reliable, more efficient, and doesn't involve any coercions nor suffer interference from `text item delimiters`.

Comment: Fair enough on the `characters`/`text` thing; changed in code. As for the rest... The idea behind automator is to extend some of the power of scripting to people who are not necessarily scripters. Simplicity and ease are far more important in that context than efficiency.

Comment: How did you get your AppleScript action to compile the script and preserve the spelling of `through`?

Comment: I'm not certain in which version of AppleScript it happened, but it seems that `thru` and `through` are name/code synonyms (different names, different four-char codes. but same functionality). Whichever is used will be kept during compile. I haven't thought about that in ages, but I think you're right that they both used to compile to `thru` (a name-only synonym). weird.

Comment: So I've used the code from above and it works great! But so far I'm running it from Automator by clicking Run. I know I can assign it to a keyboard shortcut but is there any way to keep my cmd-c and cmd-v the same but it also perform this action?

Comment: You could try saving this as an automator service and then assigning ⌘C to see if it overrides the normal cut process, but I sincerely doubt that will work (or will only work in specific contexts). a better solution might be to save it as a service and assign it a separate key-command: perhaps ^⌘C. You'd just have to remember to use the alternate cut when you wanted to filter text. Alternately, look into 'Clip Menu'. that's an alternate clipboard service that allows you to specify actions when you cut or paste.